# How can I align the button properly next to the group of checkboxes in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `html` code:

```
<div class="container">
<form name ="queryForm">

<div class="form-group">
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one">
        One
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two">
        Two
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three">
        Three
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsOther" id="checkFour" value="four">
        Four
    </p>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Reload</button>
</form>

</div>
```

and the result of this code is as on the screen below:

[image]

I want to move the `Reload` button next to the checkboxes. First I thought about moving the `<button...` right after the last checkbox, so the code would end like:

Four

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Reload</button>
</div>
```

but then the result is:

[image]

and I would prefer to have it centered vertically, something more like:

[image]

Can you give me a hint what could I modify in my code to achieve such effect?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap .btn class is inline-block, so simply move the button into the .form-group div after the final .checkbox-inline paragraph.

```
<div class="container">
 <form name ="queryForm">
  <div class="form-group">
   <p class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one">
    One
   </p>
   <p class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two">
    Two
   </p>
   <p class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three">
    Three
   </p>
   <p class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="optionsOther" id="checkFour" value="four">
    Four
   </p>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Reload</button>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `"pull-left"` class to float the form-group div and the button you can achieve this. Also, adjust the margin style how you like to suit your design.

```
<div class="container">
<form name ="queryForm clearfix">

<div class="form-group pull-left" style="margin:6px 10px 0 0">
    ....
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info pull-left">Reload</button>
</form>

</div>
```

http://codepen.io/partypete25/full/LNJyWV/

Answer (score 0):

To get the labels centered vertically to the button size, you could set the line-height of the "p" elements to be the same height as the button. Assuming the button is 24px in height:

```
//css to affect the `<p>` elements with the class of "checkbox-inline"

.checkbox-inline{display:inline; line-height:24px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply valign="middle" to button. So:

CSS:

```
button {
    valign: middle;
}
```

**OR**

HTML:

```
<button style="valign: middle;">text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your second div with a span like this:

```
<div class="container">
<form name ="queryForm">

<span class="form-group">
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one">
        One
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two">
        Two
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three">
        Three
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="optionsOther" id="checkFour" value="four">
        Four
    </p>
</span>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Reload</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your form `.form-inline`, and you do not need `.form-group` for the checkboxes, see the bootstrap documentation for inline forms: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

```
<div class="container">
  <form name="queryForm" class="form-inline">
    <p class="checkbox">
        <input name="optionsRadios" id="checkOne" value="one" type="checkbox">
        One
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox">
        <input name="optionsRadios" id="checkTwo" value="two" type="checkbox">
        Two
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox">
        <input name="optionsRadios" id="checkThree" value="three" type="checkbox">
        Three
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox">
       <input name="optionsOther" id="checkFour" value="four" type="checkbox">
       Four
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Reload</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

see this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/5mffSWq7um

this way you'll go with the standard bootstrap way, no custom css, no unnecessary html.